# Php Connection with Sql server not working on Production Server

Tags: php, sql-server

[image]

[image]

I am currently working with php. I want to connect the PHP with sql server but it is not working on the production server.It worked perfectly on my local machine, as I installed the sql server driver in the extension folder of php and activated it in php-ini file.I confirmed that the driver has been loaded into the production driver as it was hosted in a windows server and not a linux server.I need assistance,because the same script with which I connected the my local machine to the cloud sql server is the same script i am using now to connect the php application to the same sql server that is now not working. Please, I need help. take a look at my connection script that works perfectly with my local machine.

```
  $serverName = "remote sql server IP"; //a.b.c.d
   $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"sqlserverDBname", "UID"=>"sqlsvruserID", "PWD"=>"sqlsvrPassword");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
   if($conn){
       echo "Connection Established<br/>";
   }else{
    echo "Connection could not be established<br/>";
    die(print_r(sqlsvr_errors(),true));   
   }
```

?>
Both the php application and the other application that uses sql server are on the same domain, while php-app and other-app are sub domain. Kindly help look at this. Thanks community for anticipated advice/solution

Answer (score 0):

Please add **Server Name(host)** instead of **remote sql server IP** $serverName = "remote sql server IP";

This will solve your problem i think.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the production server(cloud server) or what exactly do you mean by adding : Server Name(host). How do I get that as well?

Comment: from phpinfo(), I  guessed the  Server Name will be 34-H03-S2. I used this, and it is stil showing the same error 500. Take a look at the portion of System from phpinfo()                                                             Windows NT 34-H03-S2 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586

Comment: Please use servername as below:

Comment: please, what servername do you saiy I should Use ?

Comment: Please use servername as below:
serverName:
The name of the server to which a connection is established. To connect to a specific instance, follow the server name with a backward slash and the instance name (e.g. serverName\sqlexpress).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102907/discussion-between-dave-and-nihar).